# VSCODE rearanges html classNames

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, prettier

my VSCODE (probably prettier) changes the class names I give to HTML elements. For example, this classname:
`<a className="border-green-300 rounded mr-2 border-b-2 ">`
turns into this:

`<a className="m-5 rounded-lg border-b-2 border-green-300">`
This is quite annoying as I sometimes check my second screen to see how a setting turns out (I use TailwindCSS) and if I don't like something I quickly remove it, but since it was already rearranged I just removed another class. Is there a setting to disable this? I can not find it.

Comment: It looks like you might have `prettier-plugin-tailwindcss` installed, which auto sorts the classes: https://tailwindcss.com/blog/automatic-class-sorting-with-prettier. Have you tried uninstalling it?

Comment: I definitely didn't install it myself, maybe it was installed in addition somehow. I tried to uninstall it with "npm uninstall -g prettier prettier-plugin-tailwindcss", which is probably wrong. How exactly do I do that? I can't find it in my extensions either, I only have Tailwind Intelisense there.

Comment: Are you sure it is not configured in your tailwind config file, too?

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot, I was looking in the prettier settings instead of the tailwind settings!

Comment: @Clytax what setting is it?

Answer (score 5):

visual studio extension **Headwind** by Ryan Heybourn..

visual studio extension **prettier-plugin-tailwindcss**

thnx me later..!!

Comment: Thank you! Headwind was doing this and it was driving me absolutely nuts. It kept moving conditionals around and breaking code block and white space. So annoying!